# How to perform image windowing on the OV5647 CMOS sensor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cmos, camera, python

I have an Arducam 5MP OV5647 Motorized Focus CMOS camera module (which is the same as a regular 5MP Raspberry Pi Camera, but with a motorized lens for manual focusing).

- https://www.arducam.com/product/raspberry-pi-camera-5mp-autofocus-motorized-focus-camera-b0176/

For my application, I need to quickly obtain sensor data many times a second. I don't need data from the entire sensor, however. I only need the middle 500x500 pixels.

Thus, to speed things up, I would like to only gather data from the middle 500x500 pixels on the sensor. From my research, I learned that this is possible in CMOS sensors, and is called windowing. Furthermore, based on the datasheet for this sensor (page 28 below), I know this is possible by modifying the camera registers.

- https://www.arducam.com/downloads/modules/RaspberryPi_camera/OV5647DS.pdf

I tried modifying the registers using the Python code listed at the end. The code runs and I get no errors. However, when I take a photo, I still get data from the entire sensor. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, so I was hoping someone could help. Thank you!

```
import smbus
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
bus = smbus.SMBus(0)

# Sensor values
x_resolution = 2592
y_resolution = 1944
window_size = 500

# X and Y axis starting position
x_start = (x_resolution - window_size) // 2
y_start = (y_resolution - window_size) // 2

# X and Y axis ending positions
x_end = x_start + window_size - 1
y_end = y_start + window_size - 1

# Converting positions into hex
x_start_hex = hex(x_start)[2:].zfill(4)
x_end_hex = hex(x_end)[2:].zfill(4)
y_start_hex = hex(y_start)[2:].zfill(4)
y_end_hex = hex(y_end)[2:].zfill(4)

# Writing to the registers
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3800, int(x_start_hex[:2], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3801, int(x_start_hex[2:], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3802, int(y_start_hex[:2], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3803, int(y_start_hex[2:], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3804, int(x_end_hex[:2], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3805, int(x_end_hex[2:], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3806, int(y_end_hex[:2], 16))
bus.write_byte_data(0x0c, 0x3807, int(y_end_hex[2:], 16))

camera.capture("photo.jpg")
camera.close()
```